# Show that $(M\times N)/R\cong M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

If there are two groups, $M$ (with multiplication $\cdot_M$) and $N$ (with multiplication $\cdot_N$) and we define a new group $M \times N$ with multiplication such that 
$$
(m,n)(m',n') = (m \cdot_M m',n \cdot_N n')
$$
There can be a normal subgroup $R$ of $M \times N$ such that

- $eR = \text{identity element}$
- $R = \{(eR, r) | r \in R\}$

Show that

$$
\frac{M \times N}{R} \simeq M
$$

Comment: Doesn't first isomorphism theorem do the trick under the mapping $(m, n) \mapsto m$?

Comment: What about R - the normal subgroup?

Comment: Right so FIT states if we have a group homomorphism $\phi$ from $M \to N$, then: $M / \ker(\phi) \cong Im(N)$. That gives us exactly what we want, where $\ker(\phi)$ gives us $R$.

Comment: Also I hastily ended up answering this, but please provide what you tried next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first isomorphism theorem under the mapping $\phi: M \times N \to M$ that takes $(m,n) \mapsto m$. This map is surjective onto $M$, and has kernel $R$ (since whenever $n = e$, we get mapped to the identity). Thus:

$$
(M \times N) / \ker(\phi) \cong Im(\phi) \implies (M \times N)/R \cong M
$$

You can check it to be a group homomorphism.